# Insert zero rows and columns at the same time at specific indices instead of at the end

Tags: python, numpy, indexing, vectorization

I have a 2D array (a confusion matrix), for example (3,3). The number in the array refers to the index into a set of labels.
I know that this array should actually be (5,5) instead of (3,3), for the 5 row and column labels. I can find the labels that have been "hit":

```
import numpy as np

x = np.array([[3, 0, 3],
              [0, 2, 0],
              [2, 3, 3]])
labels = ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e"]
missing_idxs = np.setdiff1d(np.arange(len(labels)), x)  # array([1, 4]
```

I know that the row and column for the missed index is all zero, so the output I want is this:

```
y = np.array([[3, 0, 0, 3, 0],
              [0, 0, 0, 0, 0],  # <- Inserted row at index 1 all zeros
              [0, 0, 2, 0, 0],
              [2, 0, 3, 3, 0],
              [0, 0, 0, 0, 0]])  # <- Inserted row at index 4 all zeros
              #   ^        ^
              #   |        |
              # Inserted columns at index 1 and 4 all zeros
```

I can do that with multiple calls to `np.insert` in a loop over all missing indices:

```
def insert_rows_columns_at_slow(arr, indices):
    result = arr.copy()
    for idx in indices:
        result = np.insert(result, idx, np.zeros(result.shape[1]), 0)
        result = np.insert(result, idx, np.zeros(result.shape[0]), 1)
```

However, my real array is much bigger, and there may be many more missing indices. Since `np.insert` re-allocates every time, this is not very efficient.

How can I achieve the same result, but in a more efficient, vectorized way? Bonus points if it works in more than 2 dimensions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this by pre-allocating the full resulting array and filling the rows and columns with the old array, even in multiple dimensions, and the dimensions don't have to match size:

```
def insert_at(arr, output_size, indices):
    """
    Insert zeros at specific indices over whole dimensions, e.g. rows and/or columns and/or channels.
    You need to specify indices for each dimension, or leave a dimension untouched by specifying
    `...` for it. The following assertion should hold:

            `assert len(output_size) == len(indices) == len(arr.shape)`

    :param arr: The array to insert zeros into
    :param output_size: The size of the array after insertion is completed
    :param indices: The indices where zeros should be inserted, per dimension. For each dimension, you can 
                specify: - an int
                         - a tuple of ints
                         - a generator yielding ints (such as `range`)
                         - Ellipsis (=...)
    :return: An array of shape `output_size` with the content of arr and zeros inserted at the given indices.
"""
    # assert len(output_size) == len(indices) == len(arr.shape)
    result = np.zeros(output_size)
    existing_indices = [np.setdiff1d(np.arange(axis_size), axis_indices,assume_unique=True)
                        for axis_size, axis_indices in zip(output_size, indices)]
    result[np.ix_(*existing_indices)] = arr
    return result
```

For your use-case, you can use it like this:

```
def fill_by_label(arr, labels):
    # If this is your only use-case, you can make it more efficient
    # By not computing the missing indices first, just to compute
    # The existing indices again
    missing_idxs = np.setdiff1d(np.arange(len(labels)), x)
    return insert_at(arr, output_size=(len(labels), len(labels)),
                                       indices=(missing_idxs, missing_idxs))

x = np.array([[3, 0, 3],
              [0, 2, 0],
              [2, 3, 3]])
labels = ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e"]
missing_idxs = np.setdiff1d(np.arange(len(labels)), x)
print(fill_by_label(x, labels))
>> [[3. 0. 0. 3. 0.]
    [0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
    [0. 0. 2. 0. 0.]
    [2. 0. 3. 3. 0.]
    [0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]]
```

But this is very flexible. You can use it for zero padding:

```
def zero_pad(arr):
    out_size = np.array(arr.shape) + 2
    indices = (0, out_size[0] - 1), (0, out_size[1] - 1)
    return insert_at(arr, output_size=out_size,
                                       indices=indices)

print(zero_pad(x))
>> [[0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
    [0. 3. 0. 3. 0.]
    [0. 0. 2. 0. 0.]
    [0. 2. 3. 3. 0.]
    [0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]]
```

It also works with non-quadratic inputs and outputs:

```
x = np.ones((3, 4))
print(insert_at(x, (4, 5), (2, 3)))
>>[[1. 1. 1. 0. 1.]
   [1. 1. 1. 0. 1.]
   [0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
   [1. 1. 1. 0. 1.]]
```

With different number of insertions per dimension:

```
x = np.ones((3, 4))
print(insert_at(x, (4, 6), (1, (2, 4))))
>> [[1. 1. 0. 1. 0. 1.]
    [0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
    [1. 1. 0. 1. 0. 1.]
    [1. 1. 0. 1. 0. 1.]]
```

You can use `range` (or other generators) instead of enumerating every index:

```
x = np.ones((3, 4))
print(insert_at(x, (4, 6), (1, range(2, 4))))
>>[[1. 1. 0. 0. 1. 1.]
   [0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
   [1. 1. 0. 0. 1. 1.]
   [1. 1. 0. 0. 1. 1.]]
```

It works with arbitrary dimensions (as long as you specify indices for every dimension)<sup>1</sup>:

```
x = np.ones((2, 2, 2))
print(insert_at(x, (3, 3, 3), (0, 0, 0)))
>>>[[[0. 0. 0.]
     [0. 0. 0.]
     [0. 0. 0.]]

    [[0. 0. 0.]
     [0. 1. 1.]
     [0. 1. 1.]]

    [[0. 0. 0.]
     [0. 1. 1.]
     [0. 1. 1.]]]
```

You can use `Ellipsis` (=`...`) to indicate that you don't want to change a dimension<sup>1,2</sup>:

```
x = np.ones((2, 2))
print(insert_at(x, (2, 4), (..., (0, 1))))
>>[[0. 0. 1. 1.]
   [0. 0. 1. 1.]]
```

<sup>1</sup>: You could automatically detect this based on `arr.shape` and `output_size`, and fill it with `...` as needed, but I'll leave that up to you if you need it. If you wanted to, you could probably get rid of the `output_size` parameter instead, but then it gets trickier with passing in generators.

<sup>2</sup>: This is somewhat different to the normal numpy `...` semantics, as you need to specify `...` for every dimension that you want to keep, i.e. the following does **NOT** work:

```
x = np.ones((2, 2, 2))
print(insert_at(x, (2, 2, 3), (..., 0)))
```

---

For timing, I ran the insertion of 10 rows and columns into a 90x90 array 100000 times, this is the result:

```
x = np.random.random(size=(90, 90))
indices = np.arange(10) * 10


def measure_time_fast():
    insert_at(x, (100, 100), (indices, indices))


def measure_time_slow():
    insert_rows_columns_at_slow(x, indices)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    import timeit
    for speed in ("fast", "slow"):
        times = timeit.repeat(f"measure_time_{speed}()", setup=f"from __main__ import measure_time_{speed}", repeat=10, number=10000)
        print(f"Min: {np.min(times) / 10000}, Max: {np.max(times) / 10000}, Mean: {np.mean(times) / 10000} seconds per call")
```

For the fast version:

> Min: 7.336409069976071e-05, Max: 7.7440657400075e-05, Mean:
>   7.520040466995852e-05 seconds per call

That is about 75 microseconds.

For your slow version:

> Min: 0.00028272533010022016, Max: 0.0002923079213000165, Mean:
>   0.00028581595062998535 seconds per call

That is about 300 microseconds.
The difference will be greater, the bigger the arrays get. E.g. for inserting 100 rows and columns into a 900x900 array, these are the results (ran only 1000 times):

Fast version:

> Min: 0.00022916630539984907, Max: 0.0022916630539984908, Mean:
>   0.0022916630539984908 seconds per call

Slow version:

> Min: 0.013766934227399906, Max: 0.13766934227399907, Mean:
>   0.13766934227399907 seconds per call

Answer (score 1):

Just another option:

Instead of using the missing indeces, use the non missing indeces:

```
non_missing_idxs = np.union1d(np.arange(len(labels)), x)  # array([0, 2, 3])
y = np.zeros((5,5))
y[non_missing_idxs[:,None], non_missing_idxs] = x
```

output:

```
array([[3., 0., 0., 3., 0.],
       [0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
       [0., 0., 2., 0., 0.],
       [2., 0., 3., 3., 0.],
       [0., 0., 0., 0., 0.]])
```

Comment: this is pretty awesome as well, why nobody had upvoted it?